# Accessing Linkbutton click event in footer of Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, footer, asplinkbutton

I am working on an asp.net project where I have a gridview on the default.aspx page databound to my sql database.  When I click on a specific row it navigates to a details.aspx page where you can see and edit the details of the row clicked.

On that details.aspx page is another gridview where I exposed the footer and added and "Insert" linkbutton and the appropriate controls for each column to add a new record into the database.  I have the entire project coded, but unfortunately nothing happens when I click on "Insert" linkbutton (Except the text in the controls all clear).  No exceptions are thrown, but no record is added to the database.  Here is the gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ClientId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ShowFooter="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Horizontal">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ClientId" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="ClientId">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClientId") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ClientId") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbInsert" runat="server" CommandName="insert" CausesValidation="false">Insert</asp:LinkButton>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MiddleName" SortExpression="MiddleName">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MiddleName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MiddleName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMiddleName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Gender") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Gender") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddGender" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>M</asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem>F</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DateOfBirth" SortExpression="DateOfBirth">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DateOfBirth") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DateOfBirth") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDOB" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ZipCode" SortExpression="ZipCode">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ZipCode") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ZipCode") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtZIP" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F4F4FD" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#5A4C9D" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D8D8F0" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#3E3277" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

and here is the codebehind:

```
 Private Sub grid1_RowCommand1(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles grid1.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "insert" Then
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters("FirstName").DefaultValue = DirectCast(grid1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtFirstName"), TextBox).Text
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters("MiddleName").DefaultValue = DirectCast(grid1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtMiddleName"), TextBox).Text
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters("LastName").DefaultValue = DirectCast(grid1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtLastName"), TextBox).Text
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters("Gender").DefaultValue = DirectCast(grid1.FooterRow.FindControl("ddGender"), DropDownList).SelectedValue
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters("DateOfBirth").DefaultValue = DirectCast(grid1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtDOB"), TextBox).Text
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters("ZipCode").DefaultValue = DirectCast(grid1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtZIP"), TextBox).Text

        SqlDataSource1.Insert()


    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks for any assistance in sorting this out!

John

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on the `grid1_RowCommand1` do you hit it when you click the link button?

Comment: Yes, the breakpoint gets hit.

Comment: assuming all the parameters have proper, expected values you should be fine.  Double check inputs and wrap the insert in a try/catch and place a break point in the catch.  Also - can you post the relevant parts of the sqldatasource markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DefaultValue doesn't set the value of what should be inserted, but rather provides resolution for null values for types that don't allow them (Integer, Long, etc).  See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parameter.defaultvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information on what that Property does.

What you'll want to do is use [Control Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.controlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) in your SqlDataSource to bind the values of your TextBoxes to the parameters used by the InsertCommand.  Use the following as an example:

```
<asp:sqldatasource id="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:YourConnection%>"
      insertcommand="INSERT INTO SomeTable (FirstName, MiddleName) VALUES (@FirstName, @MiddleName)">
      <insertparameters>
          <asp:controlparameter name="FirstName" controlid="txtFirstName" propertyname="Text"/>
          <asp:controlparameter name="MiddleName" controlid="txtLastName" propertyname="Text"/>           
      </insertparameters>
</asp:sqldatasource>
```

Then your grid1_RowCommand1 method becomes much cleaner:

```
Private Sub grid1_RowCommand1(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles grid1.RowCommand

    If e.CommandName = "insert" Then

        SqlDataSource1.Insert()

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: you might want to test that out - i'm pretty certain the data source is not going to be able to find the controls attached to your insert parameters as they reside inside the gridview and are not part of the gridview source dataset.  [See this](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/enhancing-the-gridview/inserting-a-new-record-from-the-gridview-s-footer-vb)